# RXJS Continue with concat subscribe after error

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6

I have an array of observables that need to fire off sequentially. Once an error happens, I need the to catch the error, log it, and continue observing.

At the moment, once an error occurs, the observer stops. It's essential that the observer continues and does not restart or complete on error.

```
import * as Rx from "rxjs";
const source = [
  Rx.Observable.from("1").delay(200),
  Rx.Observable.from("2").delay(150),
  Rx.Observable.throw("error"),
  Rx.Observable.from("3").delay(124),
  Rx.Observable.from("4").delay(201),
];
let sSource = Rx.Observable.concat(...source);
sSource.subscribe((v) => {console.log(v)}, (e) => {console.log(e)});
```

Current output:

```
1
2
error
```

Expected output:

```
1
2
error
3
4
```

The only solution that we could come up with was to pre-loop through the `source` observables and add catch handlers to them individually, then once an error occurs, it's handled correctly and the observer can continue without completing the entire concatenated observable.

We feel like there should be a more elegant solution to this. I'll post the solution we have at the moment if need be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can apply the `catch` operator to each of the source observables and can perform the error logging within it. Like this:

```js
const sources = [
  Rx.Observable.from("1").delay(200),
  Rx.Observable.from("2").delay(150),
  Rx.Observable.throw("error"),
  Rx.Observable.from("3").delay(124),
  Rx.Observable.from("4").delay(201),
];
const sourcesWithCatch = sources.map(s => s.catch(e => {
  console.log(e);
  return Rx.Observable.empty();
}));
const concatted = Rx.Observable.concat(...sourcesWithCatch);
concatted.subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry I've been away. This is more or less what we ended up doing yes.

Answer (score 4):

For future reference, Rxjs 5 has the `onErrorResumeNext` function that behaves like the Visual Basic `On Error Resume Next` statement.

This is the sample from the [documentation](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/error_handling.html)

```
var source = Rx.Observable.onErrorResumeNext(
  Rx.Observable.just(42),
  Rx.Observable.throw(new Error()),
  Rx.Observable.just(56),
  Rx.Observable.throw(new Error()),
  Rx.Observable.just(78)
);

var subscription = source.subscribe(
  data => console.log(data)
);
// => 42
// => 56
// => 78
```